# C language puzzle

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax, char, substitution

I am not sure if this kind of questions are appropriate here, but...
By changing (or adding) one character make this program print '*' exactly 20 times

```
void main(){
   int i, n=20;
   for (i=0; i<n; i--)
      printf("*");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your question? This will print `'*'` far more than 20 times. Change to `i++` to have it print 20 times.

Comment: only one character can be changed, to change `i--` to `i++` needs two characters

Comment: The source code presented invokes UB. On my Klingon emulator, on Waxing Crescent Thursdays (today), it prints `'*'` exactly 20 times.

Comment: I believe such questions are better suited for [codegolf.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Code Golf if anywhere. This doesn't appear to be an actual problem that the OP faces, just a puzzle they posted for entertainment.

Answer (score 12):

It seems you mean the following change from

```
for (i=0; i<n; i--)
              ^^^
```

to

```
for (i=0; i<n; n--)
              ^^^
```

Here is one character `i` is substituted for one character `n`.

Another way (if it is allowed by the puzzle) is to add one character `'-'` like

```
for (i=0; -i<n; i--)
         ^^^
```

Note: By the way pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like :)

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: @Gendozz If you are satisfied by the answer then you can select it as the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)

Answer (score 0):

either do i++ or (i-- & n-=2or any other positive number greater the 1)

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the single-character requirement.  See Vlad's answer for the correct solution to the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy, just change the `i--` to `n--`.

Maybe next Time a Harder Puzzle? ;)

Comment: What is the meaning of your answer published  4 days after the appearance of the question and my answer and that adds nothing new compared to my answer?!